# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/support/JaxWsServiceFactoryBean camel cxf spring boot xml application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, noclassdeffounderror, jbossfuse, camel-cxf

Hi I am trying to expose a camel cxf soap ws using camel spring boot.

while running the camel spring application i am getting the error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/support/JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.

Any help appreciated.

Below is the configurations:

Pom XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-ose-springboot-xml</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Fabric8 :: Quickstarts :: Spring-Boot :: Camel XML</name>
    <description>Spring Boot example running a Camel route defined in XML</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- dependency versions -->
        <fabric8.version>2.3.7</fabric8.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.5.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <fuse.version>7.1.0.fuse-710019-redhat-00002</fuse.version>
        <!-- maven plugin versions -->
        <fabric8.maven.plugin.version>3.5.34</fabric8.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.19.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--<dependency> <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId> <artifactId>fabric8-project-bom-camel-spring-boot</artifactId> 
                <version>${fabric8.version}</version> <type>pom</type> <scope>import</scope> 
                </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.redhat-fuse</groupId>
                <artifactId>fuse-springboot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${fuse.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId> 
            <version>2.18.0</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.mycompany.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId> <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>${fabric8.maven.plugin.version}</version> <executions> <execution> 
                <goals> <goal>resource</goal> <goal>build</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> 
                </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Route XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <import resource="endpoints.xml"/>
    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route handleFault="true" id="NotificationRoute" streamCache="true">
            <from id="NotificationEndpoint" uri="cxf:bean:NotificationService"/>
            <log id="route-log" message=">>> ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Endpoint xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint
        address="http://localhost:8088/eu/deferred/NotificationService"
        endpointName="nms:ICalculator" id="NotificationService"
        serviceName="nms:CalculatorService"
        wsdlURL="wsdl/notification/calculator.wsdl" xmlns:nms="http://Example.org">
        <cxf:properties>
            <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
        </cxf:properties>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="wss4jInInterceptor"/>
            <!-- <ref bean="authenticationInterceptor"/>
            <ref bean="authorizationInterceptor"/> -->
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
</beans>
```

Java Class:

```
package org.mycompany;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

/**
 * A spring-boot application that includes a Camel route builder to setup the Camel routes
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring/camel-context.xml","classpath:spring/endpoints.xml"})
public class Application {

    // must have a main method spring-boot can run
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


}
```

Error logs:

```
17:30:04.825 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@5583098b{/,[file:///C:/Users/jmjl29k/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.4312198013866550633.8080/],UNAVAILABLE}
17:30:04.855 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
17:30:04.872 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route NotificationRoute: Route(NotificationRoute)[[From[cxf:bean:NotificationService]... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:NotificationService due to: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'NotificationService': Failed to introspect bean class [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/support/JaxWsServiceFactoryBean
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.start(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:369)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at org.mycompany.Application.main(Application.java:36)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route NotificationRoute: Route(NotificationRoute)[[From[cxf:bean:NotificationService]... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:NotificationService due to: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'NotificationService': Failed to introspect bean class [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/support/JaxWsServiceFactoryBean
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:209)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1143)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3729)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3443)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:209)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3251)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3247)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3270)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3247)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3163)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:NotificationService due to: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'NotificationService': Failed to introspect bean class [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/support/JaxWsServiceFactoryBean
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:758)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1283)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'NotificationService': Failed to introspect bean class [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/support/JaxWsServiceFactoryBean
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.lookup(CamelContextHelper.java:146)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookup(CamelContextHelper.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfComponent.createCxfSpringEndpoint(CxfComponent.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfComponent.createEndpoint(CxfComponent.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:126)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:711)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'NotificationService': Failed to introspect bean class [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/support/JaxWsServiceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(ApplicationContextRegistry.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:63)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/support/JaxWsServiceFactoryBean
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
17:30:04.875 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@d83da2e: startup date [Tue Sep 25 17:29:33 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
17:30:04.997 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483646
17:30:04.998 [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: paste the content of endpoints.xml?

Comment: updated the entire project is available in https://github.com/ravi21588/SO/tree/master/Calculator

Comment: This class is part of https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/3.2.6/bundle

Comment: Yes it is transitive dependency of camel cxf and is available inside BOOT-INF/lib of the packaged application.

Comment: There's a "noclassdeffound" tag, especially for this exception. I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuse does not support `spring-boot-starter-jetty`, so replace it with `spring-boot-starter-undertow` (also remove the `<version>` tag for this dependency).

Similar for `cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty`, change it to `cxf-rt-transports-http-undertow`. You'll need to set the version for this dependency to `3.1.11.fuse-710022-redhat-00001`, as for some reason it's not in the Fuse BOM.

Finally for the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, you can change the groupId / version to this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.redhat-fuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${fuse.version}</version>
    ...
</plugin>
```

That was enough for me to run your sample project and browse the endpoint WSDL.

Comment: Thanks,It seems there was some environment issue.anyways i had done the changes as recommended by you and redhat and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you must first let the command "mvn -U clean compile" be executed successfully, so your pom.xml have some issues, try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-ose-springboot-xml</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Fabric8 :: Quickstarts :: Spring-Boot :: Camel XML</name>
    <description>Spring Boot example running a Camel route defined in XML</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- dependency versions -->
        <fabric8.version>2.3.7</fabric8.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.5.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <fuse.version>7.1.0.fuse-710019-redhat-00002</fuse.version>
        <!-- maven plugin versions -->
        <fabric8.maven.plugin.version>3.5.34</fabric8.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.19.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--<dependency> <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId> <artifactId>fabric8-project-bom-camel-spring-boot</artifactId> 
                <version>${fabric8.version}</version> <type>pom</type> <scope>import</scope> 
                </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.redhat-fuse</groupId>
                <artifactId>fuse-springboot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${fuse.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId> 
            <version>2.18.0</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.mycompany.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId> <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>${fabric8.maven.plugin.version}</version> <executions> <execution> 
                <goals> <goal>resource</goal> <goal>build</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> 
                </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```